# Unix scripting for finding files & deleting them based on a given size

Tags: shell, unix

I'm working on a unix script that has 2 input parameters - **path** and **size**.

The script will check all the files in the given **path** with the given **size** and deletes them. If the delete operation fails, the respective file-name is recorded into a file. For any other case, the file is rendered without any action.

I have written a short code (don't know whether it works).

```
find $path -type f -size +${byte_size}c -print | xargs -I {}
if $?=1;
then
rm -rf {};
else
echo {} >> Error_log_list.txt'
```

where
**`$path`** is the path where we search for the files.
**`size`** is the input size.
**`Error_log_list.txt`** is the file where we send the non-deletable filenames.

Can anyone please help me verify whether it is correct?

Comment: Be careful, posting such `rm -rf` without checking can be dangerous. Change it to `ls` until you are sure it works.

Comment: What is the error or problem you are facing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Executing your script results in the following syntax error:

```
   ./test.sh: line 9: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
   ./test.sh: line 11: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

Moreover the condition of the if statement seems not correct.
If I am not wrong it tests the return code of the "rm" command before to
execute the command.

I am not familiar with xargs and I tried to rewrite your script
using a while loop construct. Here my script

```
#!/bin/bash

path=$1
byte_size=$2

find $path -type f -size +${byte_size}c -print | while read file_name
do
    rm -f $file_name
    if [ ! $? -eq 0 ]; then
        echo $file_name >> Error_log_list.txt
   fi
done
```

I tested it trying to delete files without the right permission and it works.

Comment: I removed -r switch from the rm command as suggested by @devnull

Answer (score 1):

GNU find has a `-delete` option for this exact use case. More information (and a number of different approaches) in the [`find` documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_node/find_html/Deleting-Files.html).

```
find $path -type f -size +${byte_size}c -delete
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a script, please check this functionality

```
a=`find . -type f -size +{$size}c -print`

#check if $a is empty

if [ -z "$a" ]
then
echo $a > error_log.txt
#if a is not empty then remove them
else
rm $a
fi
```

Let me explain what we are doing here.

1. First assigning the file_names in current directory (which satisfy
   size requirement) to a variable 'a'
2. Checking if that variable is
   empty (empty means there is no file with your size requirement) if a
   has some values then delete them